# Azure Data Factory CopyData Activity issue, error code 2200

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I am about to schedule the database insertion using Azure Data factory.

I am having 1 copydata and 2 lookups 1. Max Id inserted in destination table(LastValue in json code) 2. Max id from source table (Max).

To get the lookup value in Copy Data, i've written a query like i mentioned below but still i am getting error and i am unable to fetch Lookup value in select query.

select  *  from `customer` where  created_at>=curdate()-30 and  id > @{activity('CDNOps_LastUpdateValue').output.firstRow.LastValue} and id <= @{activity('Source_MaxValue').output.firstRow.Max limit 20000}

Please help me out on this.

The error message i am getting while scheduling the data is,

"errorCode": "2200",
"message": "Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorOdbcOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][MariaDB] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"LastValue":540418183}\n and id<={"Max":546239715}' at line 2.........

Answer (score 1):

the below syntax should be the right one:

```
select * from customer where created_at>=curdate()-30 and id > @{activity('CDNOps_LastUpdateValue').output.firstRow.LastValue} and id <= @{activity('Source_MaxValue').output.firstRow.Max} limit 20000
```

Please note that when you wrap lookup activity output into @{}, this means you're trying to dynamically evaluate the value at the run time, so put "limit 20000", which doesn't belong to the lookup output, into [@{}](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#expressions) cause the error. Also ensure that `@{activity('CDNOps_LastUpdateValue').output.firstRow.LastValue}` and `@{activity('Source_MaxValue').output.firstRow.Max}` would be evaluated into a value that is comparable with column id in the table (same type at least). A small tips for debugging, you could create a user property in copy activity on UI to actively check whether the evaluated query result is what you want, see the picture below:
[image]
[image]
[image]